# Data-confirm before post in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a basic crud based gii. I use modal bootstrap to view the form.
I have code like this :

```
if ($request->isGet) {
            return [
                'title' => "Cancel Incoming : $container",
                'content' => $this->renderAjax('_form_cancel_incoming', [
                    'model' => $model,
                    'min_urut' => $min_urut,
                    'max_urut' => $max_urut,
                    'bundles' => $bundles,
                    'tanggal_real_masuk' => $tanggal_real_masuk

                ]),
                'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-left', 'data-dismiss' => "modal"]) .
                    Html::submitButton('Cancel', [
                        'data' =>[
                            'confirm' => "Apakah Anda Yakin Cancel ?"
                        ],
                        'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
                        'title' => 'Cancel',

                    ])

            ];
        } else if ($model->load($request->post())) {
              // Can I catch the data-confirm here ?
              // If yes, operating the models

              return [
                'forceReload' => '#crud-datatable-pjax',
                'title' => "Your Information",
                'content' => "<h3 class='text-success'>Cancel Berhasil</h3>",
                'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-left', 'data-dismiss' => "modal"])
            ];

        }
```

My problem is, data-confirm is show, but the operation in post still working, not wating the data-confirm.

Please advise.

Comment: $request = Yii::$app->request; do you have this in before if loop?

Comment: This is the $request = Yii::$app->request;

Comment: And tell us more about your problem?you mean validation not happening ?

Comment: I dont use validation, just when use click cancel button, I need  confirm dialog...